# Nuxt3 HMR not working, page reload needed for HMR to fire

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3, hot-module-replacement

I've installed and run Nuxt3 by

```
npx nuxi init <project-name>
cd <project-name>
npm i
npm run dev
```

This appeared in console:

```
Nuxi 3.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    09:52:01
Nuxt 3.0.0 with Nitro 1.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   09:52:01
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              09:52:01
  > Local:    http://localhost:3000/ 
  > Network:  http://172.17.181.194:3000/

✔ Nitro built in 374 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 nitro 09:52:03
ℹ Vite client warmed up in 1341ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                             09:52:03
```

After making a change in *app.vue* and hitting save, nothing happend.

Then when I click reload in chrome, this appears in the console and the page shows the right data:

`✔ Vite server hmr 6 files in 20.051ms 09:52:30`

I have node v18.3.0.
Tried the same process on node v16.15.1.

Comment: Just checked, and It's working perfectly fine. What kind of changes are you making? and is there any error on the console?

Comment: I'm also running it on WSL2 if that changes anything. Only error in console: welcome.vue:1  Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: You're trying to work by opening a tab on the `http://localhost:3000` URL right? WSL is indeed not helping but that should work well. The MIME type indicates that your local dev server is not serving the files properly for some reason, hence my question.

Comment: That's right, I'm accessing it on http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 2):

I had to change vite.server.hmr.port from 3000 to something different in

**nuxt.config.ts**

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    vite: {
        server: {
            hmr: {
                port: 3008
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Apparently port 3000 was already being used.

Answer (score 1):

I spend hours trying different settings, but the problem - Nuxt ignoring your hmr settings. (Nuxt 3.8.2)
So you just need extend vite config in hook:

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: false },
  ssr: false,
  css: [
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    '~/assets/scss/main.scss',
  ],
  vite: {
    server: {
      // In my case I use Nginx reverse proxy
      // with self signet certificate (mkcert)
      // so I just want this works on localhost:3000
      // but these settings ignoring. You can check hmr is false
      // in 'vite:configResolved' hook
      // And the most efficient and elegant way to fix it is
      // override vite config in 'vite:extendConfig' hook below
      hmr: {
        protocol: 'ws',
        host: 'localhost',
      },
    },
  },
  hooks: {
    'vite:extendConfig' (viteInlineConfig, env) {
      viteInlineConfig.server = {
        ...viteInlineConfig.server,
        hmr: {
          protocol: 'ws',
          host: 'localhost',
        },
      }
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it does not affect on the problem. Maybe you did smth else for the solution?